# List bullets leave dashes when page is scrolled vertically

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser, html-lists

When the page is scrolled vertically, the list bullets leave a trail of dashes behind.

I noticed this behaviour in Firefox only.

**How to solve this issue?**

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}
li {
  text-align: left;
  list-style: circle;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width: 600px; height: 400px; overflow: auto; background-color: #EFEFEF">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
    </ul>
    <div style="height: 500px"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see a trail of dashes with this example ? : http://jsfiddle.net/rousseauo/f56avtgs/embedded/result/ I feel like the problem may be your computer.

Comment: @rousseauo No, your code shows clean.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i can't comment yet. I tried your code on firefox and it leaves dashes as you describe. But disc type does not. It seems a problem with firefox while rendering. I tried other symbols like [cjk-ideographic](http://jsfiddle.net/8z8bm23q/1/)

```
ul {list-style-type: cjk-ideographic;}
```

and it leave the dashes too. But gregorian doesn't dash